# Spring Cloud Stream: how to send a message for each partition of a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm trying to implement a mechanism to mark the end of a sequence of kafka messages.
For this reason I'm trying to send a special message (a kind of EOF) at the end of the message sequence on each topic partition. If a consumer reads all the EOF messages then it means that he has finished processing the entire sequence of messages.
Is there a way to send a kafka message for each partition of a topic?

Edit:
the topic name is discovered at runtime, so the number of partitions is not known but must be retrieved in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a `Message<?>` with a `PARTITION_ID` header.

```
MessageBuilder.withPayload(...)
    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, partition)
    .build();
```

Or configure the producer with a `partitionKeyExpression`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_producer_properties

Comment: Thanks @gary, unfortunately I don't know the number of partitions of the topic.

Comment: You can use an `AdminClient` to determine the number of partitions.